# C program to remove all repeated characters in a string

Tags: c, string, loops, for-loop, c-strings

I want to remove all the repeated characters from a string. For example, if I have:

> "aapuroo"

I want the result to be

> apuro

but it shows

> apuroo

what is my mistake here?I am a beginer pardon my mistakes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i,j,k,n;
    gets(str);

    n = strlen(str);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

        for(j=i+1; j<n;j++)
        {
             if(str[i] == str[j])
             {
                 str[j] = str[j+1];
             }

        }
    }

    puts(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Working with a result buffer rather than in-place will make it way simpler.

Comment: Also don't use  `gets`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: Note that it is never safe to use `gets()` — see [Why `gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) for the sordid details.

Comment: What do you want as the output from the input `abracadabra`?  Two main options are `abracadabra` (because no two adjacent characters are the same) or `abrcd` because all the letters except `d` are repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is invalid. Consider a string like `char str[] = "111";`.

So in these loops

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{

    for(j=i+1; j<n;j++)
    {
         if(str[i] == str[j])
         {
             str[j] = str[j+1];
         }

    }
}
```

`str[0]` is equal tp `'1'`. `str[1]` is also equal to `'1'`. So `str[1]` is substituted for `str[2]` that is also equal tp `'1'`. As a result you will get that the array contains the string `"11"`

Moreover the inner loop processes not only adjacent repeated characters but all duplicated characters in the string.

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is an unsafe function and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Use instead the standard function `fgets`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char str[N];

    fgets( str, N, stdin );

    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0;  str[i] != '\0'; )
    {
        if ( str[++i] != str[j] && str[i] != '\n' ) 
        {
            if ( i != ++j ) str[j] = str[i];
        }           
    }

    puts( str );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the string `"aapuroo"` then the program output will be

```
apuro
```

The subexpression `str[i] != '\n'` used in the if statement is present because the function `fgets` can append the new line character to the entered string. So this subexpression is used to exclude the new line character from the result string. Or you could before the loop to remove this character.

Comment: thanks much but what have you done with enum { N = 100 };??

Comment: @MustabirApurbo Try not to use "magic numbers". Use named constants.

Answer (score 0):

When you find a repeated character, you need to shift the rest of the string to the left, filling the last byte with a zero. As for your code, you just duplicate the [j+1] character and then, in your case, exiting since you are at the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100];
  // this programm is created by chandan pradhan
  gets(str);
  for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0;  str[i] != NULL;)
  {
    if ( str[++i] != str[j] && str[i] != '\n' ) 
    {
      if ( i != ++j ) 
        str[j] = str[i];
    }
  }
  puts( str );
  return 0;
}
```